# Mapping array causing performance issues React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, maps

I have a mySQL database with about 100 rows, containing the data of products I'm listing in an eCommerce app.

I have them displayed on the front-end by using Axios to get the rows from my back-end `SELECT *` statement. They are then held as an array state `const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);`.
These rows are then mapped for each row found in the table, so around 100 maps.

I have noticed with this many results performance has started to become an issue and I've heard similar issues from mapping arrays.
I've benchmarked and tinkered to find that this component is the one causing the performance issues.
I would like any solutions to improve my component's performance, without altering the structure too much.

Heres the component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function ProductCard(props) {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

    const isntDesktop = props.isntDesktop; //Constant from parent
    const isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768; //Checks if screen is smaller than mobile
    const sidebar = props.sidebar; //Sidebar state from parent component

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/products/get/')
            .then(res => {
                setRows(res.data);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });

    return (
        rows
            .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)) 
            //Map products
            .map((row, index) => {
                return (
                    /* Adjust structure for mobile */
                    isMobile ? (
                        /* Product card */
                        <div 
                            key={index} 
                            class={`${
                                sidebar ? 'border-0' : 'border'
                            } relative mt-6 py-8 px-5 rounded`}
                        >
                            {/* Heading */}
                            <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold tracking-wide text-gray-700">{row.name}</h2>
    
                            <div class="flex items-center sm:items-start space-x-5">
                                {/* Image */}
                                <img 
                                    src={row.image} 
                                    alt="product" 
                                    class={`${
                                        sidebar ? 'opacity-50' : 'opacity-100'
                                    } mt-4 min-w-[125px] sm:w-[300px] h-auto`} 
                                />
    
                                <div class="mt-4">
                                    {/* Price */}
                                    <p class="text-2xl sm:text-xl font-semibold sm:font-medium text-gray-600">£ {row.price}</p>
    
                                    {/* Keywords */}
                                    <ul class="ml-5 mt-2 space-y-1">
                                        <li class="list-disc text-gray-600">{row.keyword_one}</li>
                                        <li class="list-disc text-gray-600" >{row.keyword_two}</li>
                                        <li class="list-disc text-gray-600">{row.keyword_three}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div 
                                class={`${
                                    sidebar ? 'bg-none' : 'bg-gray-100'
                                } mt-4 py-2 px-4 flex justify-center space-x-2.5`}>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-sky-500">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M8.25 18.75a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0m3 0a1.5 1.5 0 00-3 0m3 0h6m-9 0H3.375a1.125 1.125 0 01-1.125-1.125V14.25m17.25 4.5a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0m3 0a1.5 1.5 0 00-3 0m3 0h1.125c.621 0 1.129-.504 1.09-1.124a17.902 17.902 0 00-3.213-9.193 2.056 2.056 0 00-1.58-.86H14.25M16.5 18.75h-2.25m0-11.177v-.958c0-.568-.422-1.048-.987-1.106a48.554 48.554 0 00-10.026 0 1.106 1.106 0 00-.987 1.106v7.635m12-6.677v6.677m0 4.5v-4.5m0 0h-12" />
                                </svg>
    
                                <label class="text-gray-600 text-sm">Free delivery on orders over £50</label>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="mt-4 w-full mx-auto flex flex-col sm:flex-row space-y-2.5 sm:space-y-0 sm:space-x-2.5">
                                {sidebar && isntDesktop ? (
                                    <Button
                                        type="submit"
                                        variant="contained"
                                            sx={{
                                                opacity: 0.5,
                                                bgcolor: '#6366f1',
                                                textTransform: 'none',
                                                width: '100%',
    
                                                ':hover': {
                                                    backgroundColor: '#4f46e5',
                                                },
                                            }}
                                        >
                                        View product
                                    </Button> 
                                ) : (
                                    <Button
                                        type="submit"
                                        variant="contained"
                                            sx={{
                                                opacity: 1,
                                                bgcolor: '#6366f1',
                                                textTransform: 'none',
                                                width: '100%',
    
                                                ':hover': {
                                                    backgroundColor: '#4f46e5',
                                                },
                                            }}
                                        >
                                        View product
                                    </Button> 
                                )}
    
                                <Button
                                    type="submit"
                                        sx={{
                                            border: ' 1px solid #38bdf8',
                                            color: '#38bdf8',
                                            textTransform: 'none',
                                            width: '100%',
    
                                            ':hover': {
                                                color: '#ffffff',
                                                backgroundColor: '#38bdf8',
                                            },
                                        }}
                                    >
                                    Add to cart
                                </Button> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div key={index} class="flex mt-6 py-8 px-5 border rounded">
                            {/* Image */}
                            <img src={row.image} alt="product" class="mr-4 w-[300px] h-auto" />
    
                            <div class="relative w-full px-5 items-center">
                                {/* Heading */}
                                <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold tracking-wide text-gray-700">{row.name}</h2>
    
                                <div class="mt-8 flex justify-between">
                                    {/* Keywords */}
                                    <ul class="ml-5 space-y-1">
                                        <li class="list-disc text-gray-600">{row.keyword_one}</li>
                                        <li class="list-disc text-gray-600" >{row.keyword_two}</li>
                                        <li class="list-disc text-gray-600">{row.keyword_three}</li>
                                    </ul>
    
                                    {/* Promo */}
                                    <div class="flex flex-col ml-5">
                                        {/* Price */}
                                        <p class="text-xl font-medium text-gray-600">£ {row.price}</p>
    
                                        <div 
                                            class={`${
                                                sidebar ? 'bg-none' : 'bg-gray-100'
                                            } mt-4 py-2 px-4 flex space-x-2.5`}>
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-sky-500">
                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M8.25 18.75a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0m3 0a1.5 1.5 0 00-3 0m3 0h6m-9 0H3.375a1.125 1.125 0 01-1.125-1.125V14.25m17.25 4.5a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0m3 0a1.5 1.5 0 00-3 0m3 0h1.125c.621 0 1.129-.504 1.09-1.124a17.902 17.902 0 00-3.213-9.193 2.056 2.056 0 00-1.58-.86H14.25M16.5 18.75h-2.25m0-11.177v-.958c0-.568-.422-1.048-.987-1.106a48.554 48.554 0 00-10.026 0 1.106 1.106 0 00-.987 1.106v7.635m12-6.677v6.677m0 4.5v-4.5m0 0h-12" />
                                            </svg>
    
                                            <label class="text-gray-600 text-sm">Free delivery on orders over £50</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                                <div class="absolute bottom-0 w-full pr-5 flex space-x-2.5">
                                    {sidebar && isntDesktop ? (
                                        <Button
                                            type="submit"
                                            variant="contained"
                                                sx={{
                                                    opacity: 0.5,
                                                    bgcolor: '#6366f1',
                                                    textTransform: 'none',
                                                    width: '100%',
    
                                                    ':hover': {
                                                        backgroundColor: '#4f46e5',
                                                    },
                                                }}
                                            >
                                            View product
                                        </Button> 
                                    ) : (
                                        <Button
                                            type="submit"
                                            variant="contained"
                                                sx={{
                                                    opacity: 1,
                                                    bgcolor: '#6366f1',
                                                    textTransform: 'none',
                                                    width: '100%',
    
                                                    ':hover': {
                                                        backgroundColor: '#4f46e5',
                                                    },
                                                }}
                                            >
                                            View product
                                        </Button> 
                                    )}
    
                                    <Button
                                        type="submit"
                                            sx={{
                                                border: ' 1px solid #38bdf8',
                                                color: '#38bdf8',
                                                textTransform: 'none',
                                                width: '100%',
    
                                                ':hover': {
                                                    color: '#ffffff',
                                                    backgroundColor: '#38bdf8',
                                                },
                                            }}
                                        >
                                        Add to cart
                                    </Button> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                )
            })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you (probably) want to fetch your data once (on mount), you will have to add an empty dependency array to your `useEffect` to avoid infinitely running a query . You can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects (In the Note section).

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/products/get/').then(res => {
    setRows(res.data);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}, [])
```

I saw that you render all your data on render and unfortunately, [React is notoriously slow when it comes to rendering large lists](https://krausest.github.io/js-framework-benchmark/2022/table_chrome_107.0.5304.62.html). You might need to think about `windowing` your data, aka rendering a chunk of your data when your page first load and render more data as the user scroll further down. There's a great library that handles this for you: https://tanstack.com/virtual/v3/docs/guide/introduction.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank ill look into that. Just adding an empty dependency made my lighthouse score go from around 50 to 80.

Comment: For anyone else viewing this issue, I didn't use react-window or anything similar as I found it made my performance and I didn't want the constraints of the overflows it sets. So instead I used `.slice(0, limit`) Limit being a variable so I could change it with `onClick()` events.